# How to use spring state machine with nested state machine

Tags: spring, state-machine

Good Day,

I just started learning spring state machine.

I have the following questions
I will like to know how to configure a state machine that uses a nested state machine.

How can this be done programmatically i.e. via state machine builder?

How can this be done via papyrus UML?

My second question is on how to fire events i.e. upon getting to the state that has the nested state machine. How can events be a trigger in the nested state machine?

My third question is how to exit a nested state machine by firing an event that moves from the parent state (i.e. the state that references the nested state machine)
to another state in the parent state machine.

I would really appreciate a reference to some examples.

Answer (score 0):

After studying the javadoc and reading a few links

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/121

I figured it out.

Programmatically

1. Configure the state and transitions for the parent state machine as usual

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-state-machine

Follow that link to see how.

2. For States that reference a nested state machine. See the below snippet

....

```
enter code here

*builder.configureStates()
            .withStates()
                .initial("contactList2")                
                .state("newContactSM", newContactSM())
                .end("end1");*
```

....

The state "newContactSM" references a nested state machine. The nested state machine
is define

....

*

```
public StateMachine<String, String> newContactSM() throws Exception
    {
        
         logger.info(" ------  newContactSM() -------- ");
         
         
        // checkCurrentFlow();
        
        Builder<String, String> builder = StateMachineBuilder.builder();
        
        builder.configureConfiguration().withConfiguration().machineId("newContactBTF");
        
        logger.info(" configure states ..");   
        
        builder.configureStates()
            .withStates()
                .initial("newContact")
                .end("end2")           
                .states(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("otherContact")));   // (Arrays.asList("S1", "S2", "S3")));
        
        logger.info(" states configured ! ");
        
        
........  //
}
```

- 

```
enter code here
```

....

To do it via UML
Just ensure that you reference the nested state machine in the state "newContactSM".

Once the set up is done. You can fire events as normal. spring state machine handles the rest.